# Desencontro do .append com length

Tags: jquery

Tenho um script para gerar imagens, e as imagens são geradas com `.append`.

```
$(".fotos").append("<img src='" + size +"'/>");
```

O problema é que o append não gera a imagem no código fonte, elas são geradas a partir do próprio script, assim eu não consigo contar quantas imagens tem.

Eu uso isso pra contar, e sempre retorna 1, sendo que aparece 10 imagens.

```
alert($('img').parent('.fotos').length);
```

E é como eu disse, só retorna 1.

Existe outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `$(".fotos > img").length` para selecionar todas as imagens cujo pai tem a classe fotos.

O teu código actual seleciona todas as imagens, depois seleciona o pai com classe fotos, e faz a contagem dos pais